# select distinct in cdbcriteria yii

Tags: php, yii, substring, distinct, criteria

I'm still new using yii 1.6

I want input this condition in `CDbCriteria`

```
select DISTINCT substring(datetime,1,7) from sale
```

I try this code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'substring(datetime,1,7) like :q';
$criteria->params = array(':q' => '%'.trim($q).'%');
$criteria->distinct = true;
$criteria->select = 'datetime';
$result = Sale::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

If there is date in the same month it came out twice

I try to change this

```
   $criteria->select = 'datetime';
```

to this code

```
 $criteria->select = 'substring(datetime,1,7)';
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there better way to make it work?
thanks

Comment: Try this `$criteria->select = array( 'substring(datetime,1,7) as dtString' );`

Comment: i've try that code, but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Try this by adding the distinct function in the select portion

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'DISTINCT substring(datetime,1,7) AS dtime';
$result = Sale::model()->findAll($criteria)
```

Comment: i tried that code, but it cannot show the distinct value. there is some date in the same month, and it come out twice.